# My Scenario Outline doesn't seem to output in format I've seen before

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I've decided to start refreshing my memory on how cucumber works. And today I've come across something that doesn't really look farmiliar. I'm using a data table to make the test scalable. When I generate the output from the scenario it seems to produce loads or arguments? Why? What am I doing wrong?

I've tried adding strings to my step definitions.

```
@Given("^I navigate to cover checker site$")
public void i_navigate_to_cover_checker_site() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I add the registration number and search$")
public void i_add_the_registration_number_and_search(String registration) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I will be presented cover start and cover end (\\d+) FEB (\\d+) : (\\d+) : (\\d+) dates$")
public void i_will_be_presented_cover_start_and_cover_end_dates(String coverStart, String CoverEnd) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

}

So here is my scenario:

```
Feature: Covercheck


      Scenario Outline: : Registration number check
        Given I navigate to cover checker site
        When I add the registration number <Registration> and search
        Then I will be presented cover start <CoverStart> and cover end <CoverEnd> dates

        Examples:
          | Registration | CoverStart            | CoverEnd              |
          | OV12UYY      | 09 FEB 2022 : 16 : 26 | 18 FEB 2022 : 23 : 59 |
```

THe output:

```
@Given("^I navigate to cover checker site$")
public void i_navigate_to_cover_checker_site() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I add the registration number OV(\\d+)UYY and search$")
public void i_add_the_registration_number_OV_UYY_and_search(int arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I will be presented cover start (\\d+) FEB (\\d+) : (\\d+) : (\\d+)$")
public void i_will_be_presented_cover_start_FEB(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^cover end (\\d+) FEB (\\d+) : (\\d+) : (\\d+) dates$")
public void cover_end_FEB_dates(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

From what I remember you'd put the strings into your definitions your data in the feature files scenario outline.

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing steps correctly in your feature file under Scenario Outline.You have Registration,CoverStart & CoverEnd under examples which shall be closed between <> in your respective steps in feature file like - When I add the  number, similarly others 2.I give you one example.

Please have a look for better understanding of how to implement Example & Data Table.

```
  @BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User
  Scenario Outline: Validation of UseCase Guest User Order Placement flow from Search
    Given User is on Brand Home Page <Site>
    And User searches for a styleId and makes product selection on the basis of given color and size
      | Style_ID  | Product_Size | Product_Color |
      | TestData1 | TestData1    | TestData1     |
      | TestData2 | TestData2    | TestData2     |
    Then Clicking on Cart icon shall take user to Shopping Bag
    Then Clicking on Proceed To Checkout button shall take user to Shipping Page
    And Submitting FN as <FName> LN as <LName> Add as <AddL1> ZCode as <ZipCode> PNo as <PhoneNo> EmailID as <EmailID> shall take user to payment page
    And Submitting CCardNo as <CCNo> Month as <CCMonth> Year as <CCYear> and CVV as <CVV> shall take user to Order Review Page
    And Click on the place order button
    Then Verify order gets placed successfully and capture the Order ID in excel as CellNo as <CellNo>
Examples: Checkout User Information
  | Site  | EmailID   | FName     | LName     | AddL1     | ZipCode   | PhoneNo   | CCNo      | CCMonth   | CCYear    | CVV       | CellNo    |
  | Site1 | TestData3 | TestData2 | TestData2 | TestData2 | TestData2 | TestData2 | TestData1 | TestData1 | TestData1 | TestData1 | TestData1 |
```

Comment: Not sure I follow your answer if I'm honest.  So Should they not be examples and just be in a table? Or follow their respective steps in a table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match as Strings, try the following:

```
@Given("^I navigate to cover checker site$")
public void i_navigate_to_cover_checker_site() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I add the registration number (.*) and search$")
public void i_add_the_registration_number_and_search(String registration) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I will be presented cover start (.*) and cover end (.*) dates$")
public void i_will_be_presented_cover_start_and_cover_end_dates(String coverStart, String CoverEnd) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

The `(.*)` will match the Strings; make sure to put them in the right place in your step & step definition though. 
You'll have to convert the Strings to Dates yourself in the step definition.

Comment: Ok this makes more sense. Why has it started throwing out loads of nonsense and started bringing out the data into the output? Have I not setup me feature correctly?

Comment: THe above doesn't work despite making sense org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'coverchecker.StepDefinitions':

Comment: If it is suggesting to implement your step definitions, this means that Cucumber is not finding your step definitions. Check the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/community/faq/#cucumber-says-my-steps-are-undefined-but-i-have-implemented-step-definitions)